# При отладке модульных тестов Visual Studio выдаёт ошибку об отсутствии метода Main

Tags: c#, visual-studio

При попытке запустить отладку модульных тестов C# Visual Studio выдаёт ошибку об отсутствии метода Main и о том что не может найти файл Test.exe. Пытался найти информацию о том как отладить отдельные методы, делал всё как там, но ошибка осталась. Может кто-нибудь знает в чём дело?[image: скриншот программы и ошибок]

Comment: Для начала откройте Test Explorer.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov чутка тяжело по началу. Освоится будет смеяться

Comment: Скажите, TestAI - это самостоятельно приложение, которое должно запускаться? Или всё же это должна быть библиотека, которую потом будут вызывать из других программ? В первом случае нужен метод Main (или код в стиле Minimal API), во втором случае нужно тип проекта сменить с Application на Class Library (в свойствах проекта).

Comment: Ну что там, нашли решение проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут просто

1. Вы пытаетесь запустить проект модуля. (он у вас активный в солющен эксплорере) Посмотрите внимательно на активный проект. (F5 пытается запустить активный проект, а это модуль без main)
2. Для запуска/дебага модульных тестов используется тест эксплорер ну или меню Test => Run/Debug All Tests

Comment: Попробовал запустить через Test Explorer, но выдало ту же ошибку

Comment: а в экплорере показывает что есть тесты? Он видит или нет?

Comment: Да, показывает.

Comment: ну вот нажмите на дебаг олл или ран олл. Там в эксплорере свои меню и кнопки

Comment: Я уже много раз пробовал и через explorer и просто правой кнопкой мыши но проблема не исчезает

Comment: проблема исчезнет когда создадите проект с маин и будуте запускать его а не модуль

Comment: Это и так понятно, но почему то у всех работает а у меня нет

Comment: потому что вы пытаетесь запустить модуль. А все не пытаются и ошибки нет. Если все также будут пытаться запустить модуль без маин будут тоже ошибка